# How to inject my database context into all my repository classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

Each of my repository classes look like this:

```
public class ProfileRepository : IProfileRepository{

   private MyEntities myEnt = new MyEntities();
   ...

}
```

I am injecting my repository classes like so:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
            kernel.Bind<IProfileRepository>().To<ProfileRepository>();
            ....
            GlobalHost.DependencyResolver =  new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);
            GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IConnectionIdGenerator), () => new MyConnectionFactory());
            RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));
        }
```

I want to inject MyEntities context into all my repository classes so I don't have an instance of it in each repository class.  How do I accomplish this?  Would this be a better practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you'd be better off using the [Ninject.MVC3](http://nuget.org/packages/Ninject.MVC3) package. It will save you the burden of attaching Ninject into the framework and will only let you worry about bindings.

You can then use 
   `kernel.Bind<your-database-context>().ToSelf().InRequestScope()` .

This will make sure all your repositories will get the same DbContext if they are created in the same MVC request.

Note: You can't use InRequestScope() without Ninject.MVC3.

That said, I think repositories are an absolutely awful abstraction. You need to go through many hoops to abstract away your data access, just for unit testing. You'd be better off not abstracting away your data access (Microsoft already did a mighty fine job with Entity Framework) and just preparing a decent database copy for your unit-tests. Django does something similar for unit testing, I wonder if there's a unit testing system that handles this automatically (including applying migrations that are newer than the unit-test-only-database-snapshot).

Comment: So in other words I shouldn't inject my context into my repositories anyway?

Comment: If you have repositories, you *must* inject your context into them, and you *must* make sure you only have one context per request (actually, that's not a must, but it'll make your life a lot easier). I'm saying - don't have repositories at all, there are better ways to get unit-testing done.

Comment: @anthonypliu: you should. By not injecting the context you just can't properly control the lifetime of your context in different scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

I've accomplished this by creating a generic interface, i.e. `IMyEntitiesContext`.

Now, I'm writing this from memory at the moment, so this may or may not be 100% correct:

Something like this:

```
public interface IMyEntitiesContext : IDisposable
{
    IDbSet<Profile> Profiles { get; }
    ...
    ...
    int SaveChanges();
}
```

Then, change your DbContext class to implement this interface:

```
public MyEntities : DbContext, IMyEntitiesContext
{
    public IDbSet<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Now, you can set up constructor/property injection by using IMyEntitiesContext:

```
public ProfileRepository : IProfileRepository
{
    private IMyEntitiesContext _ctx;

    public ProfileRepository(IMyEntitiesContext ctx)
    {
        _ctx = ctx;
    }
}
```